# iOS - show UIPIckerView made in Storyboard instead of keyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uipickerview

I need to show UIPickerView instead of keyboard along with cancel/done buttons. So I created a PickerViewController.h/.m and built a view in Storyboard:
[image]

**PickerViewController.h**:

```
@interface PickerViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>;
@property NSArray *data;
```

**PickerViewController.m** has picker delegate methods:

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.data objectAtIndex:row];
}
-(CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 25;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
}
```

Now I'm trying to use it in another ViewController to show up on editing of text field:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle: nil];

PickerViewController *pickerVC = (PickerViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                              instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"PickerViewController"];
pickerVC.data = @[@"house",@"land",@"office"];
UIView *picker = pickerVC.view;
picker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 210);    
self.textFieldRealtyType.inputView = picker;
```

However when picker is being shown it's empty. Is it possible to use "standalone" picker from storyboard or do I need to create it programmatically?

Comment: Will it work if you make `pickerVC` a class variable?

Answer (score 1):

There's a built in way to show a custom keyboard (including picker views) with a toolbar, and it will behave just like the system keyboard.

For the view that becomes first responder (could be a text view like with the system keyboard, or any custom view) override the `inputView` property (which will be the picker view) and the `inputAccessoryView` (which will be the toolbar).

This way you don't need to make your own view controller, and presentation (animations etc) will be handled by the system and behave just like the normal keyboard.

If you're making a custom view become first responder, make sure to override `canBecomeFirstResponder` to return YES.

More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html

Answer (score 0):

Answering by myself.

First off, I forgot to attach `dataSource`/`delegate` of pickerView to PickerViewController in storyboard - that's why it it was empty.

Next, (thanks @vokilam for solution!) - I've got BAD_ACCESS error (which means something was **nil** when it shouldn't). So I changed `pickerVC` to `self.pickerVC` (added @property in .h file) - and now everything works fine!